# Using the for loop to combine lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a code here:

```
print('Hello Alex! Please tell me how many different shells you collected.')
pukaAlex = int(input('Puka: '))
coneAlex = int(input('Cone: '))
driftwoodAlex = int(input('Driftwood: '))
seaglassAlex = int(input('Sea Glass: '))
starfishAlex = int(input('Starfish: '))
lstAlex = [pukaAlex, coneAlex, driftwoodAlex, seaglassAlex, starfishAlex]

print('Hello Bay! Please tell me how many different shells you collected.')
pukaBay = int(input('Puka: '))
coneBay = int(input('Cone: '))
driftwoodBay = int(input('Driftwood: '))
seaglassBay = int(input('Sea Glass: '))
starfishBay = int(input('Starfish: '))
lstBay = [pukaBay, coneBay, driftwoodBay, seaglassBay, starfishBay]

lstAlexTwo = [('Puka', pukaAlex), ('Cone', coneAlex),
              ('Driftwood', driftwoodAlex), ('Sea Glass', seaglassAlex),
              ('Starfish', starfishAlex)]
lstBayTwo = [('Puka', pukaBay), ('Cones', coneBay),
             ('Driftwood', driftwoodBay), ('Sea Glass', seaglassBay),
             ('Starfish', starfishBay)]

print('Alex\'s List: ', lstAlexTwo)
print('Bay\'s List: ', lstBayTwo)
```

I know that I have other option of combine lists, however I'm not completely sure how to combine the numbers of Pukas and Cones from Alex's and Bay's list with a **`for` loop** to create a sum of the two, whilst creating a new list.

I know that I can use the + character to add the two

Sample output:

```
[('Puka', 52), ('Cone', 21)]
```

Assuming the total Puka collected is 52, and Cones are 21.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is time with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: Actually, Stack Overflow is a perfect place to ask questions. That's what this community is for. I don't need homework help, or whatever you think I need help with. I need a question answered for ONE thing. So I don't need to be told how to find my answers, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can combine the values. Then you can do what you did at the end and tupple them with the strings in a new list.

```
newList = []
for i in range(len(lstBay)):
    newList.append(lstBay[i] + lstAlex[i])
```

Comment: Why not just "tuple them" in the `for` loop instead of making a separate pass through the resulting list?

Comment: I didn't know you can even use for loops to combine or tuple. This makes sense to me, but, tuple? Does that mean I would use zip()?

Comment: Try this when lstBay is longer than lstAlex, and I think you'll spot a significant flaw.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
new_list = [(name, val1+val2) for (name, val1), (_, val2) in zip(lstAlexTwo, lstBayTwo)]
```